# Is there a way to force-close a single tab instead of the whole webpage with multiple open tabs in IE 8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Internet Explorer 8 freezes on me a lot and I'm tired of reloading the ten tabs I have open instead of just closing and re-opening the one tab that froze.  I can't use Task Manager because it closes every page open.  WinPatrol doesn't help either.

Is there a program or something I could use to **force**-close one tab while leaving the other tabs untouched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The reason the tab is frozen is that it is unable to perform operations, including cleaning up such that the tab can be closed without harming the other objects in the same container.

Comment: And since IE hosts all of it's tabs in a single process, when one tab dies or locks up, so do the rest.

Comment: @afrazier: Yep. It's a tradeoff. This is the negative part of that tradeoff.

Comment: Any of the other browsers work as multiple processes?

Comment: AFAIK, only Chrome. Firefox is planning on it, but making such a fundamental change takes time, since it breaks so many underlying built in assumptions about how the browser was built and is expected to work. Not sure about Opera.

Comment: What is AFAlK??

Comment: @verve: AFAIK = As Far As I Know

Comment: That's why I like Google Chrome............

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to IE 9 which will kill individual tabs that hang.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121060942/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ie/archive/2011/04/19/hang-resistance-in-ie9.aspx)